# Flutter: Add a Note count from Firebase Database

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Im trying to add a note count next to the "child: Text('Calculus 2)" but it give me a red underline for _noteCount = snapshot.data!.docs; . The result would be to get all note count under 'ACALnotes' and place it next to the calculus 2 text. Is that possible to do?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class _AdminScreenState extends State<AdminScreen> {
  final Color backgroundColor;
  int _noteCount = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getNoteCount();
  }

  void _getNoteCount() async {
    DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('ACALnotes').doc();
    setState(() {
      _noteCount = snapshot.data!.docs;
    });
  }

Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
    const SizedBox(width: 45, child: Icon(Icons.calculate_outlined)),
    Flexible(
      child: Text('Calculus 2 ($_noteCount notes)',
        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 18
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I have tried _noteCount = snapshot.documents.length; but it doesnt seem to work. Currently changed to _noteCount = snapshot.data!.docs; like my home_screen.dart but same issue.